# Alternate which plot gets new line?

Tags: r

I'm collecting data over time which I'd like to plot in two studies on the same plot. At issue for me is the order of how the data is gathered and added to the plot as time proceeds. For the sake of example, the following code plots the same set of random values twice and adds two lines to each study:

```
# 2 figures arranged in 2 rows
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
set.seed(123)
A = sample(seq(from = -2, to = 2, by = 0.1), size = 10, replace = TRUE)

plot(seq(1:10),A, main="Plot 1")
abline(1.2,0, col="red") #First line added
abline(-0.3,0, col="blue") #Third line added

plot(seq(1:10),A, main="Plot 2")
abline(0.7,0, col="green") #Second line added
abline(-0.5,0, col="purple") #Fourth line added
```

What I need to do is execute both plot commands at the beginning and then execute the addition of the 4 lines in the order of red, green, blue, purple. I.e. add a line to the top study, add a line to the bottom study, and as new data appears alternate between the two studies. I.e. - I'd like the code to execute like:

```
plot(seq(1:10),A, main="Plot 1")
plot(seq(1:10),A, main="Plot 2")
#Wait awhile
abline(1.2,0, col="red") #First line added
abline(0.7,0, col="green") #Second line added
#Wait awhile
abline(-0.3,0, col="blue") #Third line added
abline(-0.5,0, col="purple") #Fourth line added
```

How might I do this in R, hopefully using plot and not one of the more esoteric plot libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `mfg` argument of the `par()` function.  For example:

```
A <- sample(seq(from=-2, to=2, by=0.1), size=10, replace=TRUE)

par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
plot(seq(1:10), A, main="Plot 1") 
    abline(1.2, 0, col="red")
plot(seq(1:10), A, main="Plot 2") 
    abline(0.7, 0, col="green") 

par(mfg=c(1, 1))
    abline(-0.3, 0, col="blue")

par(mfg=c(2, 1))
    abline(-0.5, 0, col="purple")
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the way I was hoping to go. By the time I get completely finished with the plots I will likely flip back and forth on the order of 1000 times so it needed to be something quite simple. This fits the bill nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to just recreate the entire plot each time.  Create the 2 plots, then when the first additional data comes in, redraw the 1st plot and add the line, then redraw the 2nd plot and redraw the line.  When more data comes in: redraw the 1st plot add the 1st line, add the 2nd line, ...

If you really insist on not redrawing the plots then you can draw the 1st plot and save the graphics options using something like `par1 <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)`.  Then draw the second plot and save the options again `par2 <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)`.

Now you can go back to the 1st plot by first resetting the plotting parameters then using `par(mfg=c(1,1))`.

For example:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))

plot( 1:10, 1:10 )
par1 <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)

plot( 101:110, 110:101 )
par2 <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)

par(par1)
par(mfg=c(1,1))
abline(h=5)

par(par2)
par(mfg=c(2,1))
abline(h=105)
```

You can keep going back and forth with `par(mfg=...`, but remember to also set the graphical parameters as well.